# I'm getting "System.Collections.Generic.List" instead of data from database

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm working on a project to develop a UWP app. I have implemented Sqlite database to store information about products.

I have a combobox in my page that displays the serial number of all the products. I've written the code for `SelectionChanged` event of the combobox as:

```
private void InvoiceSerial_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = conn.Query<Product>
            ("select brand from product where serial=?", InvoiceSerial.SelectedItem.ToString());
        InvoiceBrand.Text = a.ToString();
    }
```

But instead of displaying the brand name, I'm getting this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Inventory+Product]
```

`InvoiceBrand` is a textbox

Comment: A  list can contain multiple. Use `Product p = query.FirstOrDefault(); if(p != null){ InvoiceBrand.Text = p.brand; }`

Comment: What is supposed to do a ProductList (or even a single Product) with the ToString() method?

Comment: Your solution worked @TimSchmelter Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I got it to work thanks to @TimSchmelter

Now my code looks like this:

```
    private void InvoiceSerial_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = conn.Query<Product>
            ("select brand from product where serial=?", InvoiceSerial.SelectedItem.ToString());
        Product p = a.FirstOrDefault();
        InvoiceBrand.Text = p.Brand;
    }
```

Comment: From [Enumerable::FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx): *"The default value for reference and nullable types is null."* Your code (unlike the comment it is based on) doesn't handle the case, where `p == null`. Since this is not the general case it should at least be noted, that `p.Brand` can raise a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Noted. Thanks @IInspectable

Answer (score 2):

Even if the result of an SQL query is exactly one row and one column, query functions in any language are still required to return a full table, to handle the general case where a resultant table has multiple items. The object you're looking for should be the first object in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` variable is probably of type `List<MyProject.Product>`, and that's why calling `a.ToString()` returns the string representation of the type!

What you should probably be doing is retrieving the first element (just use `a[0]`) and then output the value of the "brand" field.

Comment: I did what you said but when I assigned a[0] to the brand field I got an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyProject.Inventory.Product' to 'string'

Comment: I know, that's what I meant with 'then output the value of the "brand" field'! Anyway, I see you've solved your problem, so please mark your answer as the correct one! :)